# En collapse de Bootstrap, cambiar imagen según cual haga collapse con jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Buenas tarde estoy utilizado el collapse de bootstrap. Estoy haciendo un jquery para que cuando haga collpsed uno de ellos cambie la imagen que tiene, al final es una flecha hacia arriba o hacia abajo, según si esta desplegado o no. Esto lo he conseguido, pero si una vez desplegado uno me voy a abrir otro sin cerrar el primer abierto la flecha no cambia, se queda la de abierto.

```
<div class="card_faq">
  <a class="btnFAQ collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
     <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
       <div class="d-flex">
         <div class="mr-auto ">
           <h5 class="mb-0">
             ¿Qué ocurre después de registrarme y pagar?
           </h5>
         </div>
         <div class="">
           <div class="">
             <span class="if-collapsed color_flecha_abajo"><img src="{{ asset('images/svg/down-gris.svg') }}" alt=""></span>
             <span class="if-not-collapsed color_flecha_arriba" style="display: none;"><img src="{{ asset('images/svg/up-gris.svg') }}" alt=""></span>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </a>
              
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
       <div class="card-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high.....
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

 .........
```

Mi jquery:

```
<script>
    $(".btnFAQ").click(function() {
        //$(this).find('div, .if-collapsed').css("opacity","0");
        if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')){
            $(this).find(".if-collapsed").hide();
            $(this).find(".if-not-collapsed").show();
        }else{
            $(this).find(".if-collapsed").show();
            $(this).find(".if-not-collapsed").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Puede haber un función que haga que cuando pulso uno los demás se cambie la imagen?

Comment: Probaste ? Con `is()` en vez de `hasClass()` ? En el if ?

Comment: Deja de funcionar @NarcisoAifuz

Comment: Entonces en tu CSS debe faltar la clase `.collapsed`. Ó se puede agregar con el evento `click()` la clase al mismo botón:  `(this).addClass("collapsed")` . Ó en tu CSS así:  `.btnFAQ.collapsed{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```javascript
$(".btnFAQ").click(function() {
  $('.if-collapsed').show();
  $('.if-not-collapsed').hide();
  if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
    $(this).find(".if-collapsed").hide();
    $(this).find(".if-not-collapsed").show();
  }
});
```

Con eso lo que hacemos es esconder todas las flechas `if-not-collapsed` de una vez, y tan solo mostrar la activa, que se corresponde con la incluida dentro del elemento de la clase `.btnFAQ` pulsado. El resto lo hace el componente [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/#accordion-example) de bootstrap 4.

### Explicación al detalle:

1. Mediante esta instrucción mostramos todas las flechas a la vez hacia abajo de todos los elementos que tienen esa clase:

```
$('.if-collapsed').show();
```

2. Con esta otra escondemos todas las flechas a la vez hacia arriba de todos los elementos que tienen esa clase:

```
$('.if-not-collapsed').hide();
```

3. Y ahora tan solo queda mostrar la que se corresponde con el elemento con la clase **.btnFAQ** que se ha pulsado, verificando primero si tiene la clase *collapsed* con un condicional (quizás no haria ni falta el condicional en este caso, pero por si acaso lo he dejado puesto):

```
if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
    $(this).find(".if-collapsed").hide();
    $(this).find(".if-not-collapsed").show();
  }
```

Y de este modo, gracias al `$(this)` que nos referencia al elemento pulsado, escondemos la flecha encontrada mediante el find() con la clase `if-collapsed` usando el hide(), y luego mostramos la otra con la clase `if-not-collapsed` del mismo modo pero usando `show()`.

Comment: Estupendo, funciona a la perfección. Pero puedes detallar un poco lo que hace? me gustaria comprender porque si funciona así

Comment: No tiene un gran misterio, he ampliado la explicación por tu petición, pero yo tan solo he agregado un par de líneas, el resto ya era tuyo. Saludos!